# Python FBX SDK – How to enable auto-complete?

Tags: python, pycharm, maya, fbx

I am using Pycharm to code with Python FBX SDK, but I don't how to enable auto-complete. I have to look at the document for function members. It's very tedious. So, does anyone know how to enable auto-complete for Python FBX SDK in editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Copy these two files
  `[PATH_TO_YOUR_MOBU]\bin\config\Python\pyfbsdk_gen_doc.py`
  `[PATH_TO_YOUR_MOBU]\bin\config\Python\pyfbsdk_additions.py`
  to another folder like
  `d:\pyfbsdk_autocomplete` for instance.
- rename the file `pyfbsdk_gen_doc.py` to `pyfbsdk.py`
- add the folder to your interpreter paths in PyCharm. (Interpreter Settings, Show All, Show paths for interpreter)

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I got stuck with FBX SDK. I am trying to rescale the whole scene of the fbx. I know there a method called "convertScene()" that will change scale factor and scale and translate value of each object. However, I only want to change scale and translate value without changing scale factor. Do you know there is method in FBX SDK can make it? Thanks!!

Comment: I don't have an example for scaling the whole scene, sorry. If the answer to your original question helped you, could you mark the answer as accepted answer?

Comment: What is MOBU? I just don't get it.

Comment: Mobu is short for motionbuilder.